# Using a smarty foreach variable within php tags

Tags: php, smarty

I have the following smarty code:

```
  {foreach from=$additional_fields item=v}
    {if $v.fieldid eq 5}
       {php}
         // several pounds of php code here
         $myfieldid = {$v.fieldid}; // this is wrong
       {/php}
    {/if}
  {/foreach}
```

I'm trying to grab the current field id with my custom php code, in other words {$v.fieldid}.  I've found a few posts referencing $this->_tpl_vars[somevar] to get smarty variables when inside the {php} tags, but that doesn't seem to work with foreach.

I realize that using the {php} tags in smarty is counter-intuitive to the whole smarty concept and like totally lame, but I have my reasons.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change $myfieldid = {$v.fieldid}

to

$myfieldid = $v['fieldid'];

by the way what you are doing is evil!

Comment: Pure evil!  Bingy, that didn't work inside the php tags.  In your example, php is looking for an array named $v, but $v is a smarty variable, so it doesn't exist in the php world I suppose.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is kind of old topics, I managed to solve it combining a bit of suggestion from Bingy.

First you get the smarty variable into php by using get_template_vars then take the array value.

```
$v = $this->get_template_vars('v'); 
$myfieldid = $v['fieldid'];
```

OR:

```
$myfieldid = $this->_tpl_vars['v']['fieldid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP already in a smarty template, why don't you implement foreach as PHP loop and not smarty loop?

Comment: There is a bunch of smarty code inside that foreach.  I simplified the code for this question.  @Bingy - will try your tip and get back to you later today.